# how to update elements with a specific class in angular template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm just getting started with my first angular project, and I'm using Angular UI to pass through Jquery UI selectable. What would be the best way to have one element in a template update only the elements that are currently selected (e.g., that have a class of 'ui.selected')?

Comment: your question is not clear  could you explain little more about the problem

Comment: I'm using Angular with Jquery UI, so that I can use Jquery UI's selectable interaction. I would like to have an input element in my template that updates the value of other elements only if they are currently selected (e.g., have a class of 'ui-selected').

Comment: I'm not sure how to word that more clearly. Basically I want to have an input that acts as a model, and other inputs that bind to that model only when selected. Obviously I could manipulate the DOM via the UI callback functions, but I'm trying to understand if there's a better (Angular) way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by using a directive.

In app.js...

```
mymodule.directive('hotlink', function () {

    return function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$watch(attrs.hotlink, function (value) {
            if(element.parent().hasClass('ui-selected')){
                scope.obj[attrs.hotlink] = value;
                element.val(value);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and in partial.html...

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="workspaceCtrl">
<div class="editor four columns">
    <input type="text" placeholder="title" ng-model="title" />
    <textarea placeholder="description" ng-model="description"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="eight columns">
    <ul class="fileObjects" ui-jq="selectable" ui-options="selectOptions">
        <span ui-jq="sortable">
            <li class="item" ng-repeat="obj in fileObjects">
                <input type="text" val="{{obj.title}}" placeholder="title" hotlink="title"/>
                <textarea placeholder="description" hotlink="description">{{obj.description}}</textarea>
            </li>
        </span>
    </ul>

</div>
</div>
```

Now i have a conditional binding, whereby the element only gets update from the model if it is currently selected.

Comment: There is also a ui-sortable directive FYI

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @ProLoser, and also a ui-selectable directive. So essentially I should be able to implement these two without having to load the full JQuery library? Nice.